# Any recent changes in how contacts identify themselves to the Mirror API?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I'm concerned - when I take a picture, I usually (ie, last week) am able to share the image to my app.

Now, however, only Google + contacts appear as share targets. For example, if I turn off sharing to G+, I get no Share options at all, only a greyed-out Share dialog that says "Visit google.com/myglass to add friends"

However, when I go to that address I clearly see my app and a number of contacts (who aren't in G+) who also usually show up.

Has something changed to cause this behavior? For example, is the code listed in the starter-project no longer sufficient to register a share target for photos?

For example, I could imagine that suddenly the `acceptTypes[]` parameter was now mandatory. But I'd love to hear someone closer to the API weigh in, if possible.

Thanks!

AKA

Comment: Not that I'm aware of: can you make sure that your sharing Contact is enabled in the MyGlass website? Make sure to click on the "Sharing contacts" tab.

Comment: Oh wow, that was it - sorry for the confusion! I'll update this question and call out your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot seem to find the "Sharing contacts" tab. The only tabs I have are: Setup, MyGlass, Glassware, Explorers, and Support.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by following [Alain's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106381/alain) comment's advice.

It's very easy to think that the "Contacts" page you see at https://glass.google.com/myglass is all there is.

But **if you want your app to receive shared stuff, you have to go here**: https://glass.google.com/myglass/share